# "This site can't be reached localhost refused to connect"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, connection, localhost

I started a OmniStack course this week and created all the necessaries files and folders. When I was just starting, the instructor asked us to write the following code in a index.js file.

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.send("Hello World");
});

app.listen(3333);
```

But when I went to check the localhost:3333 (and some others that I've tried) I get this message from my browser saying that the site can't be reached, localhost refused to connect and "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

I have all the thing the instructor asked to install, such as nodejs and yarn, the code was succesful when he presented but I just can't make it work here, I can't find what's causing the problem

Comment: Are you launching your server by running Node (or via some build tool)?

Comment: You need to start the server by running `node index.js` or by running the script from with VSC prior to loading your browser.